# My table layout keeps moving from the center over the the left, Unable to find out why

Tags: android

I am trying to create a table layout with a relative layout beneath it in an attempt to create a tic tac toe game in android studio. For whatever reason, whenever I add in the relative layout beneath the table layout, everything moves around in a strange manner. Everything is supposed to be in the center, and if you remove the relative layout part, it works. However, I need to use the relative layout and center it for the button and text.

I've tried googling, switching around the set up for the layout and such, but I can only get it to work with the table layout below the relative layout (Which isn't what I need)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <TableRow>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/square1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/square2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/square3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow android:layout_width="313dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/square4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/square5"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/square6"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/square7"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/square8"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/square9"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</TableRow>


<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
<TextView android:id="@+id/infoLabel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="user's turn"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/NewGame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/infoLabel"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:text="Reset"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

</TableLayout>
```

I expect everything to be in the center, with the Table Layout on top, then the text that states the user's move, then the button, all centered. Instead, The table layout moves to the left, the text stays in the center, and the button moves to the right.

Comment: can you post the code

Comment: Is the code not there? All the layout specifications is the only code I have.

Comment: How do you handle clicks of buttons?

Comment: The buttons are not meant to function atm. I am currently setting up the GUI for the app.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out what my issue was. I simply needed to add

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

to each of the table rows I had created. So it looked like this:

```
<TableRow android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/square1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/square2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/square3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/square4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/square5"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/square6"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/square7"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/square8"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/square9"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</TableRow>
```